# Web browser doesn't open in RSelenium

Tags: r, firefox, browser, rselenium

I'm trying to move my first steps with RSelenium so after setting up server I launched

```
 remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
 remDr$open()
```

Everything looks fine, I'me able to navigate and so on, unfortunately I can't see my session because browser doesn't open. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you running docker. If so you will need to use the debug image and vnc to view the browser. See the docker vignette for details.

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-docker.html#debugging-using-vnc

Comment: Yes, I'm running docker but I a little bit confused... I followed you instruction but it seems to me that in section "remote control/debbugging with windows" there is some kind of linux code. Guide says: "You will be asked for a password which is secret. This can be seen by reading the images dockerfile" but the code to obtain it seems to me non appropriate for windows os... some kind of error in the guide?

Comment: The vnc server for the container has password `secret`.